# How can I use Visual Studio to work with large non-VS codebase?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm a fairly experienced C# dev, but have very little C++ knowledge. I have set my self a project to get a custom Firefox build running, and be able to control it from C# code.

I have got so far as getting and building the Firefox source, and creating a Visual Studio solution for the exe. This means I can now run via F5 in Visual studio. If I open a source file, I can set break points and have them hit.

What I'm not sure how to do, is load the entire source, as if I were working with a C# .NET solution. As I understand it, there are no project files with the Firefox source, as it is not windows specific source. I have followed an online example that suggests creating using 'project from existing code' option in VS, which resulted in VS grinding to a halt as there were so many files.

What are the steps to getting the code into an environment (preferably Visual Studio) that makes it simple(ish) to edit, debug and navigate the source code.

Note: Instructions I have been working through so far are here: https://cs.senecac.on.ca/~david.humphrey/writing/debugging-firefox.html

Comment: So really this question has nothing to do with C# and everything to do with getting firefox compiling in visual studio. Others have tried this: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=338845

Comment: I have mentioned C# because it adds context. It demonstrates the angle I'm coming from and implies what I'm expecting. I have been able to build the source, this question is more to do with the ability to easily "edit, debug and navigate the source code.". I can't use that link, it's old and not particularly clear.

Comment: The context is that you have a C++ code base that you wish to load and run in a C++ IDE. Removing the C# tag. :)

Comment: The point of the link wasn't really to give you an answer, otherwise I would have posted that as an answer. And the reason that link isn't particularly clear is because apparently it's very difficult. 22 pages of discussion over the course of 4 years usually tells me that this is very difficult.

Comment: Why the close vote? This is a very good question which a lot of C++ devs would like to have answered.

Comment: Did you see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Windows_Build_Prerequisites?

Comment: @AShelly. Yes thanks. I am able to build Firefox, it's information on use with Visual Studio that I'm interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a command line build path, which is creating a VS-debuggable executable,  you could try adding all the source files to the project, but marking them 'exclude from build'.    Then add a 'post-build step' to call the command line tools.

You may have to do a little more tweaking in the project properties to get the command line output recognized as the output to debug, but theoretically this could work.

Comment: This sounds like the most feasible approach so far. Thanks +1

Answer (score 2):

From you question, I beleive you are almost there. You have a working build ? That means you have :

1. A Solution File (*.sln)
2. A Project file (*.vcxproj or *.vcproj depending on yoru visual studio version)

With that in hand, what works best for me is this layout (adapted to your needs) :

- Starting from a root folder of you liking, say `MyProject`
- Create a new Empty solution there
- Move the folder with your working build in a subdirectory, like `MyProject\MyCustomFirefox`
- In Visual Studio "Add an existing project" and find your vcxproj file
- In the same solution, create a C# project like you always do, in a directory at the same level as your FF build, like `MyProject\MyFirefoxController`

In short the solution file is pretty much alone in the root directory, and each project is in its own directory.

You will also need to adjust build options so that the output files (a DLL or an EXE) is seen by your C# project. While your are at it, make the C# project dependent on your Firefox build : it will instruct the msbuild to rebuild one if you change the other.
This will not work with the Express edition, I beleive. They are single language.

Comment: Thanks. The build was created using the command line tools. The project file that I have is empty, other than to have some properties set, one of which instructs Visual Studio to run Firefox.exe when debugging. In that respect, the C++ project file doesn't contain any source files. To debug, I'm using file > open. So I'm not really building from Visual Studio, just debugging. Also, source files are not included within the Visual studio solution.